# Laravel query issue whene user is deleted

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin

Here is my database table.

`to_user_id` is deleted in the `users` table that time `total_like` not should be 1
Here is my code

```
$user_id = 585;
$list = new self;
$list = $list->where('users.id', $user_id);

$list = $list->leftJoin('user_like_dislikes as total_like', function ($join) use ($user) {
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'total_like.to_user_id')
        ->where('total_like.like', 1);
});

$list = $list->select('users.*', \DB::raw('count(total_like.like) as total_like')
$list = $list->first();
```

Here are my `user_like_dislikes` data table

| user_id | to_user_id | like |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 585 | 590 | 1 |

Here is my `user` table

| id | deleted_at |
| --- | --- |
| 590 | Null |

I above code `to_user_id` is not deleted in the user table so the output is total like is 1

But when I delete `to_user_id` in the users table that time output is total like 1 getting. this is wrong.

So, I want where I delete `to_user_id` in the users table that time total like should be 0

Answer (score 0):

better way use relation to get solve this problem.

try bellow code :

in user model :

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function likes(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class, 'to_user_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

the Like model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Like extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_like_dislikes';

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And Finally your query is:

```php
  $data =  \App\Models\User::query()
        ->where('id',585)
        ->withCount('likes as likes_count')       // for getting count of rows
        ->withSum('likes as likes_sum','like') // for getting sum of like column
        ->first();
```

#### `$data->likes_count` and `$data->likes_sum` your want value

and for handle soft delete you should use bellow tarit in `user` model

```php
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```